# What plant(s) should I grow for cocktail usage?

Tags: ingredients, cocktails

I considered growing some spice plants for cocktail usage. My question is which plants should I grow?

I know mint is used in Mojito and a lot of other drinks (as a decoration and an ingredient). I already have a mint plant, and wondered what a good choise for a second spice plant would be.

Preferably a plant that could be used in multiple cocktails. I think I read about a drink that used rosemary as a decoration. Is that a good choise?

Comment: Think about what cocktails you like that have herbs, fruit or berries in them, and grow those. I like growing strawberries, raspberries, mint and rosemary for drinks. I would grow limes if I could here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Rosemary is a great plant for cocktails that have bourbon and/or lemon.  It compliments very well.

Lavender is another. Cocktails that work well with lavender tend to use gin. The herbiness of gin mixed with the floral aromatic flavors of lavender are great.

Comment: Hi Scivic, thanks for the answer!  Can you expand on the types of cocktails lavender would complement like you did for rosemary?  That would be helpful.

Comment: Cocktails that work well with lavender tend to use Gin.  The herbiness of Gin mixed with the floral aromatic flavors of Lavender are great.

Comment: what about mint?

Comment: Mint works very well but you'd need to muddle it as well to release the oils and essence.  Mint and white rum is top notch

Answer (score 2):

**What plant(s) should I grow for cocktail usage?**

This question reminds me of the liqueur Chartreuse made with 130 herbs, plants and flowers.

> [Chartreuse](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chartreuse_(liqueur)) is a French herbal liqueur available in green and yellow versions that differ in taste and alcohol content. The liqueur has been made by the Carthusian monks since 1737 according to the instructions set out in a manuscript given to them by François Annibal d'Estrées in 1605. It was named after the monks' Grande Chartreuse monastery, located in the Chartreuse Mountains north of Grenoble. Today the liqueur is produced in their distillery in nearby Aiguenoire. It is composed of distilled alcohol aged with 130 herbs, plants and flowers.

In all fairness, drinking Chartreuse is an acquired taste. It quite different.

Plants I would grow for cocktail usage would be mint, rosemary and basil.

- [Cocktails in the Gardening](https://www.gardeners.com/how-to/cocktail-gardening/8532.html)

Comment: It looks like this answer is mostly a placement for Chartreuse, and doesn't particularly answer the question, except for a related link.